# Make content in DataGrid columns which is populated by an sql table clickable, like a link

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

How do I make it so that in the fields containing links in the image below, I can click on the link and that navigate me to the link I clicked on?
I have populated this using the SqlDataSource tool which come with asp.net; connecting it via a connection string to the DB.

Any advice would be helpful!

Thanks,

Callum

UPDATE

I have now solved the error. I have now custom data bound the datagrid with data; therefore I can have control over what goes into the gridview.

Thanks for all help!

[image]

Comment: which asp.net control you are using for links??

Answer (score 0):

You can use Template Field in second columns instead and add Hyperlink control in that column. then `Bind` or `Eval` the NavigateUrl and Text to your column value.

Comment: Ah ok, could you please show me an example of how it would look?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Simple Lable then you can't use for Navigation

```
  <asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" 
                  ImageUrl="images/pict.jpg"
                  NavigateUrl="http://www.microsoft.com"
                  Text="Microsoft Official Site"
                  Target="_blank"
                  runat="server"/>
```

[Source Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.target%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)